# Bootstrap 4 tabs does not work with owl carousel 2

Tags: tabs, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel, bootstrap-tabs

I try to add bootstrap tabs functionality within the owl carousel 2. But it does not work properly.

First time click on any menu item it works fine and shows proper related value but **when clicking for the second time** it does not work. Stuck at **last clicked value**. Also, the **classes do not change from the second click**.

HTML

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">111111111111</div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">2222222222222</div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">3333333333333333</div>
   </div>
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme tab-slide" id="" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"><img src="imgs/gallery/gal-1.jpg"></a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false"><img src="imgs/gallery/gal-2.jpg"></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false"><img src="imgs/gallery/gal-3.jpg"></a>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tab-slide").owlCarousel({
        'items': 2,
        'nav': true,
        'navText': ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>']

    });
});
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by does not work properly and include any steps you have taken to remedy the issue on your own. Is there any documentation you have read or other things you have researched to help solve the problem?

Comment: First time click on any menu item it works fine and shows proper related value but when clicking for the **second** time it does not work. Stuck at last clicked value. Also, the **classes** do not change on the second click.

Comment: add this to your original question so that other users who come across this can have a better picture of how to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old issue we had on our first beta of Bootstrap, if you update to our latest release (beta 2) everything should work

Comment: Nothing changed!
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/dreamdev/pen/BmaGNv)

Comment: Yep you're right it seems it's a conflict between Owl Carousel and Bootstrap 4, because Bootstrap 4 and Owl Carousel use the same _.active_ css class